# Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, gac

I have an ASP.NET website that uses the Oracle.DataAccess.dll.  I have version 10.2.0.100 and 1.111.6.0 in the GAC of my local machine, but only 10.2.0.100 on the dev server.  When I deploy the website to the server and run the website, I get this error before the website even loads:

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=1.111.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"
```

I guess I need to build my app against the 10.2.0.100 version but I don't see how to do that.  If I remove the 1.111.6.0 version from the GAC on my LOCAL machine and try to rebuild, I get the error above.

How do I resolve this issue? How do I build against a certain dll even if there are more than one version of that dll in the GAC?

Answer (score 3):

If your server is a 64bit machine, enable execution of 32 bit applications in IIS.

*Application pools >> Advanced Settings >> Enable 32bit Applications.*

Answer (score 1):

Look into Redirecting Assembly Versions

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a version to use. Bobby found the link I was looking for, nice one.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, when you select the reference from the Add Reference dialog you can chose witch version do you want ...

[image]